# Whats the difference between do while and while in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, loops, while-loop, do-while

What's the difference between **Do While** where the statement is the first line in the loop block and just the single **While** in VB.NET?

They don't seem to offer any difference in behavior.

Comment: There is no difference. One is there for legacy reasons. BASIC is an ooooooold language, and Vb.Net still carries some of that baggage e.g. `Mid(MyStr, 2) = "Hi"` want to guess what that does?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**In Visual Basic** these are identical:

```
    Dim foo As Boolean = True

    While Not foo
        Debug.WriteLine("!")
    End While

    Do While Not foo
        Debug.WriteLine("*")
    Loop
```

These are not; the `do` executes once:

```
    Dim foo As Boolean = True

    While Not foo
        Debug.WriteLine("!")
    End While

    Do
        Debug.WriteLine("*")
    Loop While Not foo
```

Comment: For completeness: `Do While Not …` can be written as `Do Until`.

Comment: Honestly, I actively avoid `Do Until`. I've seen too may people accidentally throw infinite loops into production code with it.

Comment: Great, that's the explanation I was after.

Comment: I have always used Do Until. Never had a problem with infinite loops. You just need to make sure you update the variable being tested during the loop.  If people are putting infinite loops into production code, then they're not testing it properly.

Answer (score 1):

In **DO...WHILE**, the code inside the loop is executed **at least once**

In **WHILE** Loop, the code inside the loop is executed **0 or more times**.

Answer (score -6):

`Do While` executes first and then checks if valid. `While` checks first and then executes.

```
while (1!=1){ echo 1}
```

will output nothing

But

```
do{echo 1} while (1!=1)
```

will output 1 once.

Comment: I'm not asking about the difference between do { } while and while { } end while. I'm talking about the do while { }.

Comment: There is no such thing as a do while{} in C# AFAIK

Comment: No it isn't, the DO WHILE is in the same line and the block is underneath.

Comment: Yes, but the logic is the same.

Comment: Is this a VB question or a C# question.